# ¿Como redireccionar a una vista de ajax en grails 3.8?

Tags: ajax, grails

Tengo un formulario en un Modal, y cuando le doy guardar quiero que me redireccione a la pagina de atrás, pero están echas con ajax, ahorita lo que hace es actualizar toda la pagina y se queda en el inicio de la pagina en donde tengo los ajax

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer que el método del controlador, en el que guardas los datos del formulario del modal, haga una redirección al metodo del cual se genera tu vista 'de atras'.

Seria hago parecido a esto:

```
redirect(controler: "NombreControlador", action: "NombreMetodo")
```